# Performing calculations on Dataframe columns by user and add as new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my current DF:

DF:

```
 User        time   distance
 Jeff    00:04:00      10
 Mike    00:01:00       2
 Mike    00:05:00       4
 Jeff    00:08:00       4
```

I'm looking to add two new columns - avgtime and avg velocity (distance/time). The avg time and avg vel is calculated for each user and then result is shown in each dataframe record - where the results look like this:

Desired_DF:

```
 User    time    distance   avg_time   avg_vel
 Jeff    00:04:00    10      00:06:00     1.5
 Mike    00:01:00     2      00:03:00     1.4
 Mike    00:05:00     4      00:03:00     1.4
 Jeff    00:08:00     4      00:06:00     1.5
```

Comment: How `avg_time` and `avg_vel` are calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the shared `avg_vel` is wrong, since it doesn't seem to be `distance/time`, but you probably want something along the lines of:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.time)
g = df.groupby('User')
df['avg_time'] = g.time.transform(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x.dt.total_seconds().mean()/60, 
                                                            unit='minutes'))           
df['avg_vel'] = g.distance.transform('mean')/(df.avg_time.dt.total_seconds()/60)

print(df)

   User     time  distance avg_time   avg_vel
0  Jeff 00:04:00        10 00:06:00  1.166667
1  Mike 00:01:00         2 00:03:00  1.000000
2  Mike 00:05:00         4 00:03:00  1.000000
3  Jeff 00:08:00         4 00:06:00  1.166667
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` and `transform` to obtain `avg_time`, and `map` the results of a simple division for `avg_vel`:

```
df["time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["time"])
df["avg_time"] = df.groupby("User")["time"].transform(lambda d: d.mean(numeric_only=False))
df["avg_vel"] = df["User"].map(df.groupby("User")["distance"].sum()/
                               df.groupby("User")["time"].sum().dt.components["minutes"])
print (df)

   User     time  distance avg_time   avg_vel
0  Jeff 00:04:00        10 00:06:00  1.166667
1  Mike 00:01:00         2 00:03:00  1.000000
2  Mike 00:05:00         4 00:03:00  1.000000
3  Jeff 00:08:00         4 00:06:00  1.166667
```

Answer (score 1):

Without lambda:

```
df["tim"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["tim"])
df['tim'] = df['tim'].values.astype(np.int64)

grouped = df.groupby("User")

df["avg_time"] = pd.to_timedelta(grouped["tim"].transform('mean'))
df["avg_vel"] = grouped["distance"].transform('mean') / (df["avg_time"].dt.total_seconds()/60)

df["tim"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["tim"])
df
```

Output:

```
    User    tim distance    avg_time    avg_vel
0   Jeff    00:04:00    10  00:06:00    1.166667
1   Mike    00:01:00    2   00:03:00    1.000000
2   Mike    00:05:00    4   00:03:00    1.000000
3   Jeff    00:08:00    4   00:06:00    1.166667
```

I converted the column `"tim"` to `int64` so that the mean can be computed directly with `groupby`.